# Como puedo emular un click con jquery en un carrusel teniendo una clase especifica

Tags: html, jquery

Tengo una duda que no logro resolver desde hace unos días. Estoy intentando emular un click cuando el carrusel tiene una palabra clave, en este caso coloco

```
if($('.owl-item').hasClass('center')){
   $('.click').click();
}
```

Cabe destacar que este carrusel tiene un tab dentro de otro tab el cual cuando le das a una palabra cambia a dicho tab. Para que tenga una mejor idea dejaré una imagen del mismo. Disculpen por molestar y gracias a quién me pueda ayudar de antemano

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me parece que deberías emplear el evento que cambia el texto de tu carousel, para ejecutar lo que estas buscando hacer, en lugar de emplear un evento clic emulado.